# Java Regex: Allow only certain characters, but don't allow certain characters to begin the string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm fiddling around with Java regex, and I'm trying to come up with a pattern that allows a certain set of characters anywhere else BUT it can't start with certain characters in the allowed set.

For example, let's say the allowed characters are from A to Z, but the string can't start with X or Z. How do I do that? I've come up with `^[XZ][^A-Z]+`, and while it works otherwise, it allows the string to start with other letters that are not in the set (e.g. with punctuation).

Comment: How about `[A-WY]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[A-WY][A-Z]*$
```

- `^[A-WY]` ensures that the first character is `A-W` or `Y`
- `[A-Z]*$` will match 0 or more of any uppercase English letter

**In general** to exclude certain characters you can also use negative look-ahead:

```
^(?![XZ])[A-Z]+$
```

`(?![XZ])` is negative lookahead to disallow `X` or `Z` at start.

Comment: What if the allowed character regex is hyuuuuge, do I still have to repeat it like that? Is there no way to exclude the two characters?

Comment: Check my updated answer to exclude certain characters at start using negative lookahead.

Comment: Thanks! The last part of your answer hit the spot. Will accept asap.

Answer (score 1):

Java regexes support subtraction in character classes; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, which shows these as examples:

```
[a-z&&[^bc]]    a through z, except for b and c: [ad-z] (subtraction)
[a-z&&[^m-p]]   a through z, and not m through p: [a-lq-z](subtraction)
```

So you could say

```
[A-Z&&[^XZ]]
```

to mean any upper-case ASCII letter except X or Z.  It really isn't needed here, but if you're using large classes like Posix character classes, it could be more useful.

Warning: Not all languages support this construct in regexes.  I'm pretty sure C++ and Javascript don't, and I don't actually know of another language that does but I haven't checked.

Comment: I would be surprised if JS supports this. They don't even support lookbehinds :(. This is a good answer

Comment: Though the docs call it substraction, it is more an abuse of the intersection feature. There is also support for subtraction in .net and pythons regex module. @TheLostMind JS doesn't support this, neither do Standard C++, Boost, Python re or PCRE.

Comment: @SebastianProske - Yes, many languages don't support this (ajb has explicitly stated this) :)